# Easiest way to create Jira WS client

Tags: netbeans, maven, jax-ws, jira

I'm looking for the easiest way to create a JIRA webservice client. First I tried the Jira SOAP Client example but it seems to have dependencies on libraries from the jira-rpc-plugin. I want to call the webservice from a remote server so I was looking for the JAR version of said plugin, unfortunately the download link in the plugin repository doesnt seem to work.

So I tried to build it myself. But I got kind of stuck with the maven project when imported into Netbeans, it tells me the project is malformed and gives me a ton of errors. I don't want to get into the hassle to set up maven manually so I tried another method.

I wanted to consume the WSDL as a Webservice Client in Netbeans but when I try to generate a JAX:WS style client, I run into a problem with "undefined simple or complex type soapenc:Array". Now the next step would be to download the old JAX:RPC plugin - is this really necessary?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this guide - it worked for me (but I'm working with eclipse)
http://www.j-tricks.com/1/post/2010/08/jira-soap-client.html

Francis

Answer (score 1):

seems the JAX-RCP plugin is not so actively supported. 
If you add http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz to the Netbeans plugin settings, you will find it though.